# Google Recaptcha incorrect-captcha-sol

Tags: validation, recaptcha

I've got a Google recapture that refuses to accept my answers (error: incorrect-captcha-sol) yet I think I've test every step without any problems. Its on a simple HTML/CSS type site.

- I can see in Firebug that the response and challenge are being sent from the contact form.
- I've echoed back the fields in php and they are the same I'm sending (match firebug)
- I've got a table on the same page but its not part (or in any way related) to the contact form.

HTML code:

```
<!-- Contact Form -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span9">
                <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="#">

                    <p class="contact-name">
                        <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name (Required)" value="" name="name" />
                    </p>
                    <p class="contact-email">
                        <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address (Required)" value="" name="email" />
                    </p>
                    <p class="contact-message">
                        <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your Message (Required)" name="message" rows="15" cols="40" maxlength="150"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p class="contact-challenge">
                        <div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display:none">
                            <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
                            <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color:red">Incorrect please try again</div>

                            <span class="recaptcha_only_if_image">Enter the words above:</span>
                            <span class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">Enter the numbers you hear:</span>

                            <input id="recaptcha_response_field" type="text" name="recaptcha_response_field" />

                            <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">Get another CAPTCHA</a></div>
                            <div class="recaptcha_only_if_image"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')">Get an audio CAPTCHA</a></div>
                            <div class="recaptcha_only_if_audio"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')">Get an image CAPTCHA</a></div>

                            <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()">Help</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </p>

                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=XXXX">
                    </script>
                    <noscript>
                        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=XXXX" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
                    </noscript>
                    <p class="contact-submit">
                        <a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="#">Send</a>
                    </p>
                    <div id="response">
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
```

PHP

```
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "XXXX";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                              $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                              $details["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                              $details["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly

   $this->response_html .= '<p>The code you entered was incorrect, please try again. ' . $resp->error . '</p>';
   $this->response_status = 0;      
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured it out I didn't initialize $resp before I used it.
So I've now got

```
$resp = null;
```

before the start of the IF statement and the code is now working correctly.

That's what I get for copy/pasting Google's code and not checking it carefully!